# Cant un-hide css element to choose an element value with selenium

Tags: javascript, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im automating something on some website and I have a dropdown menu that is customise, now the developer that developed it set the original dropdown to be hidden, it looks like this:

[image]

now I want to choose some value of the dropdown with selenium but I cant find the element since its hidden, so I want to use js to uncheck the hidden and choose a value.

this is my html block where you can see the web elements:

[image]

Comment: What selenium language bindings are you using?

Comment: @alecxe im writing the automation in scala

Comment: Thanks, updated the answer, please edit if I'm doing scala syntacticly wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `jcf-hidden` class (or remove the class attribute completely) via "execute script".

Example in Python:

```
elm = driver.find_element_by_id("company_stage")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class');", elm)
```

In [ScalaTest](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_selenium), it should be:

```
val ele: Option[Element] = find(id("company_stage"))
executeScript("arguments[0].removeAttribute('class');", ele)
```